# Uniqueness in Nature and the tacit physicist method of "solving problems by uniqueness"

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, nature

It seems to me that it is a fairly oft-used (although rarely mentioned explicitly) strategy in physics textbooks (and perhaps the research literature) to solve problems in the following manner:

1. Make a postulate (likely based on good physical intuition and/or observation).
2. Compute the solution given the postulate.
3. Verify that the solution confirms the postulate.

But of course, strictly speaking, we are begging the question in doing this. Is it therefore fair to say that in all physics problems, it is acceptable to use that *nature converges on a unique solution* to solve problems? Can we *prove* that this is a valid strategy? Because one could conceive of the possibility (and now roughly speaking) that by making a postulate as per 1), we are "led down the wrong path" and so obtain the wrong result in 3) which nevertheless agrees with what we guessed in 1). That is to say, we can derive absurdities by assuming absurdities.

In case the general commentary I make above is not clear, below I attach an example of such a strategy from Example 6.3 of Zangwill's *Modern Electrodynamics*. NB that we 1) assume the form of $\sigma_P$ (as $\sigma_P = \sigma_P (\theta)$ so that we can use a result derived earlier for a surface density of this type), 2) compute $\sigma_P$, and 3) observe that $\sigma_P = \sigma_P(\theta)$. It's not clear to me that resolving this particular example's use of the strategy above is as simple as saying we're using the uniqueness of Maxwell's equations here (a particular physical theory) seeing as those fields are uniquely determined given a fixed functional form of the sources, but here we do not a priori know that functional form.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What question is being begged by making educated guesses and finding that the solutions match those guesses?

Comment: Suppose $x^2 = 5x$. If $x \neq 0$ then $x = 5$ which is a consistent solution in that $x \neq 0$. But is it correct? No, or at least not completely. $x=0$ is possible too but we didn't "see" it because we took a guess and went down one path. This is a toy example of what I mean @KyleKanos

Comment: Okay, so you're questioning the validity and/or use of [*trial and error*](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Trial_and_error), which means also the scientific method since they mirror each other. Cool.

Comment: @KyleKanos Not sure there's any need for sarcasm. I don't think my question qualifies as crankery; I think it's actually a fairly deep question about how Nature works. You might object that it's more a philosophy of physics question, but it's not a priori obvious that guess and check should work -- especially when we mean check in the limited sense of checking for consistency with the original guess.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a mathematical tactic. The way we prove it works is by doing experiments. No purely mathematical proof constrains reality: the universe just continues doing whatever is in its nature. It's not our job to find  perfect math, but to find math that captures the behavior of real objects.